# Text mining a webpage and extracting only <li> features

Tags: r, web-scraping, text-mining

I am trying to text mine a website for keywords but do not know how to proceed.

I either want to extract from a webpage all items with the `<li>` tag. So I have HTML code;

```
<H1> Some header </H1>
<text> Some noise I am not interested in </text>
<li> some text here </li>
<li> some more text here </li>
<li> even more text here </li>
<text> Some more noice I am also not interested in </text>
```

So I am only interested in items with lists `<li></li>`

Can somebody point me in the right direction for this.

Alternatively I have used the readLines function and save the webpage as a data_frame so I am thinking of trying to remove all rows without the `<li>` command.

Any ideas

Comment: I like Python and the Beautiful Soup module for this

Comment: You just connect to the web page, and then `soup.find_all('li')` returns all the `li` elements

Comment: Thanks, but I forgot to mention that I only program in R! sorry my bad.

Comment: Try `library(rvest); html <- read_html("link"); html %>% html_nodes("li")`

Comment: Python suggestion to R questions seem…wrong? @Mako212 Esp since R is equally if not more capable of this task.

Answer (score 0):

if you have a list of webpages you can iterate this list and use the following snippet to extract the **actual text** between `<li>-Tags`:

```
library(rvest)

scraper <- read_html("http://yourpage.com")

scraping_wiki %>%
    html_nodes("li")%>%
    html_text()
```

In your case this will return

```
    ##  [1] " some text here "                             
    ##  [2] " some more text here "  
    ##  [3] " some more text here "
```